# Script to upload every new video from Google Drive to YouTube

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, youtube-data-api

I'm in need of help to create a **script to upload new videos I send to Google Drive directly to YouTube using a bot**. I've done major part of the code, but I can't find anywhere how to get the new video URL and it's metadata, could someone please help me? Here is the code I've wrote so far below:

```
function upload(url, title, description, topics) {
    try{
        var video = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        YouTube.Videos.insert({
            snippet:{
                title: title,
                description: description,
                tags: topics
            },
            status:{
              privacyStatus: "unlisted",
            },
        },"snippet,status", video);
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("done")
    }catch (err){
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(err.message)
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have something like the following:

```js
   response = YouTube.Videos.insert({
            snippet:{
                title: title,
                description: description,
                tags: topics
            },
            status:{
              privacyStatus: "unlisted",
            },
       },
       "snippet,status",
       video
   );
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Above, `response` is a [Video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) that contains the metadata associated to your newly uploaded video.

From there on you would use `response` as you need; for example, the video ID of the newly uploaded video is to be found at `response.id`. From the ID, you could compose that video's URL as:

```js
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
        .concat(response.id)
```

Comment: I tried it, and I couldn't figure out much of what to do, I should just paste this code there and it should run? I'm trying to understand how it gets the google drive videos links as they're uploaded, but I don't understand and I couldn't make this work. Could you explain it a little bit clearer, please?

Comment: The main point is that the call `YouTube.Videos.insert(...)` returns an object, a [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) object. That returned object is assigned to `response`. From there on you would use `response` as you need; for example the video ID of the newly uploaded video is to be found at `response.id`. From the ID, you could compose that video's URL as `"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".concat(response.id)`.

Comment: I got this, it is better in my mind now, I think I can make it to work, but anyways, you explained pretty important things that I didn't know that I needed to, thank you! The problem is more actually on how to get the link as I update videos, because I don't know which method to use to get every new video uploaded in certain periods on Drive, but some algorithm will solve it.

Comment: For example, I don't know how to get the links of new videos to assign to the response variable, and I don't know if there is a function for it, or if the bot should find the videos manually by dates and stuff.

Comment: @Pedro: I imagine that your bot should somehow record on the drive (within a sort of small database) the IDs of videos it uploaded along with the video file name (and possibly more info attached to those IDs; for example the date and time stored in [`publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt)). This way your bot could easily determine which files on the drive it should next upload to YouTube (those would be the files that exists on the drive but does not exist in your database of already uploaded videos).

Comment: @Pedro: on the other hand, YouTube Data API is able to provide a list with all videos uploaded by your channel.